# $visitor = Tracker::currentSession(); return null data

Tags: laravel, package, tracker

After installing this **composer require pragmarx/tracker** package successfully when i am going to return $visitor data using above method, it shows null.

**output:**
[image]

How can i get tracker info?

Comment: Did you follow all installation instructions? https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker#installing

Comment: Of course i did everything.